# How to implement a REST API with included data in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails app which has a REST API. I manage two formats JSON and XML.
Very often to simplify the use if the API, I'm making includes. But when you add params to to_json and to_xml like :only, :except, it's not only applied on the root object but on all the objects included.

Do you know libs or methods to answer to these different problems:

- Tell never return a user password in
  the API
- Tell always include a relationship or a method in each user serialized
  in the API
- Serialize objects depending on context. For exemple, when a user ask for the user list, he should see its complete profile, a partial profile of its friends and just the name of others...
- Don't have to copy paste the parameters for xml and json

Thank you very much,

Camille Roux

Comment: It's hard to say without code and api examples

Answer (score 1):

You're likely going to want to override the `to_xml` and `to_json` methods in each model and ensure that your controller is calling those methods on your objects when returning JSON/XML.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001876 and http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873 for the default implementation of these methods.